# Using API to extract time in a specific time zone

Tags: javascript, api, time

Good Morning,

I am very new to JS and I am writing pseudo code to wrap my head around the logic behind this process. I am trying to generate a tool which checks all the available time zones and prints when it is 8am with a notification that says, [Wake up it is 8am in "That time zone or city"].

Is this something that can be done calling an API such as https://www.timeapi.io/swagger/index.html or do I have to have a list with all the time zones and have a counter so that it posts when the counter has the UTC++?

Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: I don't think an external api would still be necessary for an application like that. I believe the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` with its timezone option (works in chrome, don't know about other browsers) could work. `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-UK', {timeStyle: 'short', timeZone: 'America/Hermosillo'}).format(new Date())` would return a string of the current time in that timezone, so it still accounts for daylight savings and stuff.

Comment: Cool, Ill look into that thanks!